# Cannot add reference to WixUIExtension.dll, WixUtilExtension.dll and WixNetFxExtension.dll from Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wix

I am using WiX 3.7 with [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008), and I am trying to add a reference to few WiX DLL files so that I can work with a UI in my installation. However, I get the following error for each of the following files that I add a reference to:

- WixUIExtension.dll
- WixUtilExtension.dll
- WixNetFxExtension.dll

> A reference to C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7\WixNetFxExtension.dll could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid WiX reference.

Also, before I started thinking about moving to a UI based interface, there was no issue with the WiX installer that I am creating; it compiles and installs absolutely fine.

Please note that I am able to add reference to the same files in Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: I'm curious, if you do a "Run as Administrator" on VS, does it do the same?

Comment: @Adam Plocher - That is something i did not think of. I tried it now... but does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a workaround: Unload the WiX project and modify the project file manually to add references to the required files. I should have done that earlier... Duhh!!

Comment: You should mark this as the answer, even if it is your own.  This worked for me

Answer (score 6):

I also had problems after updating from a 2.x version of WiX to 3.7. After getting the above error message for my project, I added the lost section from my previous SVN revison with the full path like so

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <WixExtension Include="WixUIExtension">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7\bin\WixUIExtension.dll</HintPath>
      <Name>WixUIExtension</Name>
    </WixExtension>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Same answers as Vaibinewbee answer but with added code, then the project loaded and built just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of editing the project file, you should right click on the References project item and Add References to the various Wix dlls that you need to reference.

Comment: I had done this, and it was not working for me then, that is why i had to resort to manually editing the file.